# Laravel View - Import Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Getting to know laravel (using version 6) and i was wondering how i can make sure that my view is using my Vue component? In this case its the `HelloWorld.vue` component i want rendered in the `albums.blade.php` view file.

In my app.js i have made sure to register the component like this:

`Vue.component('hello-world', require('vue\src\components\HelloWorld.vue').default);`

And then im using it like this inside the `albums.blade.php`:
`<hello-world></hello-world>` and i have also made sure to include the script tag referring to `app.js` like this:
`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

- With no success... any inputs?

[See my folder structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDuoG.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use laravel mix for vue js
[Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/vue)

change your `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

to **`<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`**

Answer (score 0):

Place check **[Laravel Mix docs](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/installation)**

My personal config using **Laravel mix** is:

### app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';

window.Vue = Vue;

/** Auto register components */
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));

// Other things
// ....

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app'
});
```

### albums.blade.php

Place this script tag at the bottom of the page.

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Then you could use the component like this:

```
<div>
  <hello-world></hello-world>
</div>
```

#### Recommendation

Consider learning **Laravel 9** instead of Laravel 6. This because **9** is the **newest version** and also the **actual LTS** release.